# Is it possible to to access sms counter in windows phone 7 apps?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want to create a windows phone 7.1 application to display a messaging counter. Is it possible to access messaging counter through apps?

Comment: one of the answers below can be accepted since, they seem to answer your question convincingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there are no API's to access SMS in WP7 or 7.5 but in future if MS shows mercy then it may be possible.

[You can check this link and vote for SMS access API's.](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-app-platform/suggestions/1901813-sms-access-api)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there is no API access to this level of SMS functionality in Windows Phone